# Full width Toolbar Item in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to implement the weekday markers in a Calendar application as shown in native Calendar app:[image: Full width]

I have the following:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 7), spacing: 20) {
        Text("S")
        Text("M")
        Text("T")
        Text("W")
        Text("T")
        Text("F")
        Text("S")
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't span the entire width. None of the other [`ToolbarItemPlacement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemplacement) values seem to span the entire width. Is there any way I could implement this?

Comment: did you figure it out? i'm in the same boat

Comment: I didn't, unfortunately :(